# ActiveMQ ignoring persistent=false

Tags: unit-testing, spring, activemq-classic

I am using Active MQ for integration testing my application. I have defined an active-mq broker in a spring config like so:

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" 
           persistent="false" 
           deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true" 
           useShutdownHook="true">

    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

But it seems to be ignoring `persistent=false` and every time I run the test suite I get a folder created called `activemq-data`

What do I need to do so that Active MQ is not persistent?

Answer (score 2):

The solution, in addition to adding the persistant="false" is to comment out the following lines in your activemq.xml:

```
 <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
 </persistenceAdapter>
```

Also, doesn't hurt at this point to purge your data directory...

Answer (score 0):

I would use ActiveMQ 5.3.2 - this looks like an older release.
Btw - you don't need to deleteAllMessagesOnStartup - as you won't be using a persistent message store

cheers,

Rob

Comment: I am now using 5.3.2 and get the same result. (And how would you know I wasn't, the spring context doesn't change?)

Answer (score 0):

Even on commenting the persistent adapter, it creates that directory. When is `et broker.persistent=false` in the broker URL, though, the persistence gets disabled. I'm still wondering why, and at this point, this is in 5.4.2.